# SharePoint sensitive files and permissions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I am trying to setup permissions on some of my sensitive files in order to make them secure in the SharePoint environment and also just want those files view by specific people at my work. Is a good approach to secure the files?

Comment: Are sensitive files stored within SharePoint document library? If that is the case then you can use document level security on specific files to setup unique permissions. Just click on 'Share with' link to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can create a document library. And then break the permission inherited from its Parent.

Now you have full control on the library and choose who can view/edit documents.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to create a site collection for each team who needs specific type permission. The reason is that it is easier to manager than document library permission and easier to maintain. You just invite the people who need access to these files and nobody else know the URL unless the one you shared with. 
Again, depends on your requirements and how your environment is configured!